# NSDictionary inside NSMutableArray (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
NSArray *arrayBlockData = [data objectForKey:kData];
for (NSDictionary *dictTicket in arrayBlockData) {
      NSString *blockId = [dictTicket objectForKey:@"block_id"];
      [dictJson setObject:blockId forKey:@"block_id"];
      [self.arrblockIds addObject:[dictTicket objectForKey:@"block_id"]];
}       
[arrkeysAndValues addObject:dictJson];
NSLog(@"arrkeysAndValues %@",arrkeysAndValues);
```

reponse is :

arrKeysValues (
        {
        "block_id" = 624;
    },
        {
        "block_id" = 624;
    },

it should be : 
arrKeysValues (
        {
        "block_id" = 623;
    },
        {
        "block_id" = 624;
    }

Comment: So you want arrKeysValues as key or you want to form array of { "block_id" = 623; } dictionaries ?

Comment: Where is `dictJson` initialized?

Comment: The problem is that you set (overwrite) the object for key `block_id` in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. But the code sample on how you put NSDictionary inside NSMutableArray is

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setValue:@623 forKey:@"block_id"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict2 setValue:@624 forKey:@"block_id"];

    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [newArray addObject:dict];
    [newArray addObject:dict2];

    NSLog(@"%@", newArray);
```